# Chemical writing: the term "synthesis route"

Tags: terminology

Can someone tell me, which of the following terms should be used or avoided? (Google shows the presence of all the candidate terms.)

- synthesis route
- synthetic route
- route of synthesis
- synthesis pathway
- synthetic pathway

Imagine for example a sentence such as "A new ... was developed."

Comment: all of these seem pretty acceptable. there is no definitive rule on this

Comment: In your example, "synthetic route" or "synthetic pathway" would fit best.  I suppose it is a matter of personal style, but that's what sounds best to me.

Comment: I like concision, so I would vote for "A new synthesis was developed."  You don't need any extra words in there; the meaning is clear from "synthesis" alone.

Comment: In papers I often see "synthesis route" or "pathway"

Comment: Synthetic is an adjective, which seems to more naturally modify the following 'pathway' in English.  While I am not a native German speaker, my understanding is that combining nouns is natural in that language and as such 'Synthesis Pathway, makes more sense.

Comment: I also saw "synthesis route/pathway" often in publications, but also "synthetic synthesis/pathway". Thank you all for your answers! You helped me.

Comment: If I may comment on "concision": If the synthesis includes nearly the same procedure of what the scientist has to do, but the alteration of a single compound leads to a different pathway (reaction mechanism, scientific context), I would still choose "synthetic pathway/route". However, in most cases I would agree with you, that the addition of "pathway/route" creates redundancy.

Comment: Ask this question on English SE.

Comment: English SE sent me back for this.